# Can't get ffmpeg to use frei0r on OSX (through homebrew)

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, homebrew

I am trying to get ffmpeg to use frei0r plugin and although I was able to get frei0r show up in filters list, I get the error:

```
 [frei0r @ 0x10331c1c0] Could not find module 'glow'
 Error initializing filter 'frei0r' with args 'glow:0.5'
```

I use homebrew. 
I got ffmpeg to build with --enable-frei0r --enable-filter=frei0r the instruction from this git:

https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commit/f63399c3d0241e7534e73b9fe9d4413b151414b9

But can't get to actually using the frei0r.

EDIT: Here is full output:

```
$ ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -vf -vf frei0r=glow:0.5 output.mpg
 ffmpeg version 0.10 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers  built on Mar  4 2012       11:47:02 with clang 3.0 (tags/Apple/clang-211.10.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/0.10 --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-libfreetype --cc=/usr/bin/clang --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libxvid --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libass --disable-ffplay --enable-frei0r --enable-filter=frei0r --enable-filter=frei0r_src --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      51. 34.101 / 51. 34.101
  libavcodec     53. 60.100 / 53. 60.100
  libavformat    53. 31.100 / 53. 31.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 60.100 /  2. 60.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0.  6.100 /  0.  6.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2011-12-15 10:24:56
    encoder         : Lavf53.24.0
  Duration: 00:00:15.44, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2736 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 2604 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 48k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2011-12-15 10:24:56
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2011-12-15 10:24:56
      handler_name    : 
[NULL @ 0x7fcb9184a400] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'frei0r=glow:0.5'
frei0r=glow:0.5: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -vf frei0r=glow:0.5 output.mpg` — you had a double `-vf` there.

Comment: just tried - same result..

Answer (score 7):

try the following:

`ffmpeg -v debug -i 1.mp4 -vf frei0r=glow:0.5 output.mpg`

and you will probably see something like this:

> [Parsed_frei0r_0 @ 0x7fe7834196a0] Looking for frei0r effect in '/Users/user/.frei0r-1/lib/glow.dylib'
>   [Parsed_frei0r_0 @ 0x7fe7834196a0] Looking for frei0r effect in '/usr/local/lib/frei0r-1/glow.dylib'
>   [Parsed_frei0r_0 @ 0x7fe7834196a0] Looking for frei0r effect in '/usr/lib/frei0r-1/glow.dylib'

and ffmpeg is probably right. 
If you will `ls -l /usr/local/lib/frei0r-1/` you will see the the plug-in are installed with `.so` extension.

On my machine (OSX 10.7.3, ffmpeg 1.0 & frei0r-1.3), I just did something like:

`for file in /usr/local/lib/frei0r-1/*.so ; do cp $file "${file%.*}.dylib" ; done`

which solved the problem, because the `.so` library had 2 architectures, i386 and x86_64.

I'm sure it's not a generic solution, but it did the job for me.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem and discovered this environment variable in the ffmpeg `vf_frei0r.c` source at line 229:

```
if ((path = av_strdup(getenv("FREI0R_PATH")))) {
...
```

Consequently, setting this using

```
export FREI0R_PATH=/path/to/.so-files
```

worked for me. Replace this path with wherever your `.so` files for libfrei0r are stored.

Answer (score 0):

as of 2021 mac machines:

1. install frei0r with brew `brew install frei0r`
2. set FREI0R_PATH `export FREI0R_PATH="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/frei0r/1.7.0/lib/frei0r-1"`
3. run `for file in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/frei0r/1.7.0/lib/frei0r-1/*.so ; do cp $file "${file%.*}.dylib" ; done`
4. relaunch terminal (or `source .zshrc` if you use oh-my-zsh etc.)